# Separate Jenkins-Project for deploying to JBoss

Tags: maven, jboss, jenkins

I have a Jenkins build which builds a maven project with `-PmyProfile clean package`. This works fine. Now I want the project be deployable but in a separate task (JBoss deployment) so it can be triggered explicitly via the jenkins GUI. For that, I have the following in my pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>myProfile</id>
        <properties>...</properties>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.as.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jboss-as-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>7.0.0.Final</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <hostname>localhost</hostname>
                        <port>29999</port>
                        <username>admin</username>
                        <password>admin</password>
                        <filename>${project.build.finalName}.war</filename>
                        <name>my-webapp</name>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Now I only want to call that single deployment via `mvn jboss-as:deploy` separately. But how would I do that? If I create a second Jenkins project, everything needs to be built again, so that's pretty stupid. Building as a separate module does not work, either (some error with "building single modules not supported for maven 3").

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sucks a little, but you can always get stuff from another Jenkins workspace by using filesystem relative path like `../../SecondJob/workspace` (or use symlink). I used to do this for the same case (deploying as separate job) for all my projects and it works, it's just not elegant, but I believe there's no built-in solution in Jenkins for that.

Alternatively, it seems there's [Jenkins plugin for that](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin), but I haven't used it and can't tell anything about it.

Comment: Where exactly do you set the Jenkins workspace? I don't find an option to define where the workspace is located per project.

Comment: Workspace is somewhere in a filesystem. I doesn't matter where exactly. What is important, you can set working path of your deploy-related build to that one using this relative path hack of using `..`. Or execute shell script that copies the artifact to the current build's workspace so you can use it. Just explore a little job settings.

Comment: I found the option for Maven: It is not in the "Advanced Options" but resides under the "Advanced" button in the "build" section! So I went with this way of a "shared workspace" and that works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Possible trick:

Have only one project, but parameterize it with *DEPLOY* parameter set to *FALSE* by default. The build will contain your main build as well as an *Invoke top-level Maven targets* post-build step for deployment. The deployment step will be invoked only if *DEPLOY* is *TRUE*. To do that you use [Conditional Build Step plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin).

Comment: To (1): That means I would know beforehand whether to deploy or not, otherwise if I build first and choose then to deploy, I could do it with 2 completely separated projects. To (2): For some reason, I don't have that "Use custom workspace" option in my projects. Using Jenkins 1.455

Comment: (1) But how is it different from knowing in advance that you want to run your deployment project? (2) Ok, that option is unavailable for Maven projects. I'll remove it from the answer.

Comment: See my comment to the accepted answer. The option exists, just in a different place.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new `deploy-only` goal added in version 7.5.Final. You can grab the war from the first job with [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin).

References:

- https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/deploy-only-mojo.html
- https://github.com/jbossas/jboss-as-maven-plugin/pull/56/commits